# Multiple Joins with LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have this query:

```
 public IQueryable<PostView> PostJoinQuery()
        {
            return _context.Posts.GroupJoin(
                _context.Users,
                post => post.User_Id,
                user => user.User_Id,
                (posts, users) => new { posts, users })
                .SelectMany(
                x => x.users.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                (post, user) => new PostView
                {
                    User_Id = post.posts.User_Id,
                    Post_Id = post.posts.Post_Id,
                    Author = user.Username,
                    First_Name = user.First_Name,
                    Last_Name = user.Last_Name,
                    Created = post.posts.Created,
                    Modified = post.posts.Modified,
                    Content = post.posts.Content,
                    Profile_Picture = user != null ? user.Profile_Picture : "No picture",
                })
                .GroupJoin(
                _context.Comments,
                post => post.Post_Id,
                comment => comment.Post_Id,
                (post, comment) => new
                {
                    PostView = post,
                    Comments = comment.Count()
                })
                .Select(result => new PostView
                {
                    User_Id = result.PostView.User_Id,
                    Post_Id = result.PostView.Post_Id,
                    Author = result.PostView.Author,
                    First_Name = result.PostView.First_Name,
                    Last_Name = result.PostView.Last_Name,
                    Created = result.PostView.Created,
                    Modified = result.PostView.Modified,
                    Content = result.PostView.Content,
                    Profile_Picture = result != null ? result.PostView.Profile_Picture : "No picture",
                    Comments = result.Comments
                });
        }
```

Where I need to add another GroupJoin with the _context.Images that will do the same thing as the commnents, but now i need it to count the images

I tried the following:

```
        public IQueryable<PostView> PostJoinQuery()
        {
            return _context.Posts.GroupJoin(
                _context.Users,
                post => post.User_Id,
                user => user.User_Id,
                (posts, users) => new { posts, users })
                .SelectMany(
                x => x.users.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                (post, user) => new PostView
                {
                    User_Id = post.posts.User_Id,
                    Post_Id = post.posts.Post_Id,
                    Author = user.Username,
                    First_Name = user.First_Name,
                    Last_Name = user.Last_Name,
                    Created = post.posts.Created,
                    Modified = post.posts.Modified,
                    Content = post.posts.Content,
                    Profile_Picture = user != null ? user.Profile_Picture : "No picture",
                })
                .GroupJoin(
                _context.Comments,
                post => post.Post_Id,
                comment => comment.Post_Id,
                (post, comment) => new
                {
                    PostView = post,
                    Comments = comment.Count()
                })
                .GroupJoin(
                _context.Images,
                post => post.PostView.Post_Id,
                image => image.Post_Id,
                (post, image) => new
                {
                    PostView = post,
                    Images = image.Count()
                })
                .Select(result => new PostView
                {
                    User_Id = result.PostView.PostView.User_Id,
                    Post_Id = result.PostView.PostView.Post_Id,
                    Author = result.PostView.PostView.Author,
                    First_Name = result.PostView.PostView.First_Name,
                    Last_Name = result.PostView.PostView.Last_Name,
                    Created = result.PostView.PostView.Created,
                    Modified = result.PostView.PostView.Modified,
                    Content = result.PostView.PostView.Content,
                    Profile_Picture = result != null ? result.PostView.PostView.Profile_Picture : "No picture",
                    Comments = result.PostView.Comments,
                    Images = result.Images
                });
        }
```

But I am getting the following error:
could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'

Edit: I have also tried this, and it counts the images but not the commnets:

```
        public IQueryable<PostView> PostJoinQuery()
        {
            return _context.Posts.GroupJoin(
                _context.Users,
                post => post.User_Id,
                user => user.User_Id,
                (posts, users) => new { posts, users })
                .SelectMany(
                x => x.users.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                (post, user) => new PostView
                {
                    User_Id = post.posts.User_Id,
                    Post_Id = post.posts.Post_Id,
                    Author = user.Username,
                    First_Name = user.First_Name,
                    Last_Name = user.Last_Name,
                    Created = post.posts.Created,
                    Modified = post.posts.Modified,
                    Content = post.posts.Content,
                    Profile_Picture = user != null ? user.Profile_Picture : "No picture",
                })
                .GroupJoin(
                _context.Comments,
                post => post.Post_Id,
                comment => comment.Post_Id,
                (post, comments) => new
                {
                    post,
                    comments
                })
                .SelectMany(
                x => x.comments.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                (post, comments) => new PostView
                {
                    User_Id = post.post.User_Id,
                    Post_Id = post.post.Post_Id,
                    Author = post.post.Author,
                    First_Name = post.post.First_Name,
                    Last_Name = post.post.Last_Name,
                    Created = post.post.Created,
                    Modified = post.post.Modified,
                    Content = post.post.Content,
                    Profile_Picture = post.post != null ? post.post.Profile_Picture : "No picture",
                    //Comments = post.comments.Count() // *** THIS FAILS
                })
                .GroupJoin(
                _context.Images,
                post => post.Post_Id,
                image => image.Post_Id,
                (post, image) => new
                {
                    PostView = post,
                    Images = image.Count()
                })
                .Select(result => new PostView
                {
                    User_Id = result.PostView.User_Id,
                    Post_Id = result.PostView.Post_Id,
                    Author = result.PostView.Author,
                    First_Name = result.PostView.First_Name,
                    Last_Name = result.PostView.Last_Name,
                    Created = result.PostView.Created,
                    Modified = result.PostView.Modified,
                    Content = result.PostView.Content,
                    Profile_Picture = result != null ? result.PostView.Profile_Picture : "No picture",
                    Comments = result.PostView.Comments,
                    Images = result.Images
                });
        }
```

I need to count the comments properly

Comment: Use [navigation properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/navigations), not GroupJoin.

Comment: Yeah, the above looks really complex